# WebSocket with json in c#

Tags: python, c#, websocket

I have this python code

```
  try:
               ws = websocket.create_connection(f"{ws_server}",origin=f"url")
               ws.send(js2.dumps(JSON DATA)).encode("UTF-8"))
               ws.send(js2.dumps(JSON DATA)).encode("UTF-8"))
               ws.send(js2.dumps(JSON DATA)).encode("UTF-8"))
              
               ws.close()
           except Exception as e:
               print(e)
               pass
```

How can I make that code in c# , and send that json data too

Answer (score 0):

Try using
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=net-6.0
It's the C# TCP library

Comment: please never provide link-only answers, as they are prone to pointing to deleted resources.

Comment: @rikyeah this link points directly to the official Microsoft C# documentation. I doubt it will be deleted in the next few years

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31094381)